# How to implement Authentication Across MVC 5 Application and Seperate Web API Application

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am building an online application using AngularJS on the front-end, hosted in an MVC 5/Web API application (basically a single-page application). However I have a hard constraint: the application's data will be held in a private network. I have to build a second Web API application inside the private network that exposes the web application's functionality. Further, the user authentication needs to happen inside the private network API (so the private network API will act as the authentication provider), as this is where the user tables exist.

The app in the DMZ is basically going to act as a proxy to the web API in the private network. So every request received in an `ApiController` in the UI API will be calling the private network API, ideally passing the token on received in the initial request.

From an authentication perspective, this is what I need:

- User navigates to the site, can see only certain pages (I want to use MVC filters in the view controllers to control access).
- They will log in once with a username and password.
- After login the user can navigate to application pages and as a result the pages will call into the DMZ API for data.
- This DMZ's API controllers will be calling into the private network API.
- Both APIs whould be able to identify and apply authorization on their controller methods, based on the user's credentials.

If I didn't have a need for the second tier of API I would just use the MVC Single User Authentication implementation, which provides support for both cookie (UI) and token (API) authentication.

Any help providing insight into how I can do a similar thing with the above scenario would be much appreciated. (I guess my requirement is a bit like Windows impersonation for the UI web app).

See below for a high level view of the static architecture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Azure service bus relays](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/), which are designed to bridged the corporate firewall and call on-premise APIs.

Your WebAPI service would authenticate against the service bus to be allowed to call your service through it. You can pass user credentials using a bearer token in the request.

I'm not sure, but you may need to change your backend service implementation to use WCF though. You can find an explanation of the use of relays in Microsoft Dynamics in [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn720290.aspx).